# How to read a response of a servlet using PHP

Tags: java, php, servlets, rpc

I would like to send a request to a Java Servlet from PHP and receive the response from the same and show it on the PHP page. How should this be done?

Thanks and Regards

Abishek R Srikaanth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want is to print the response of a GET request to an external resource plain vanilla into the PHP response, then you can use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for that.

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("http://example.com/someservlet"); ?>
```

The servlet's `doGet()` method will be invoked and whatever response it returns (which can even be a forwarded JSP) will be printed as string to the PHP response.

If you want a little more fine grained control, e.g. using POST or something, then head to [`curl()`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) instead. The linked PHP manual contains several examples.

Regardless of the way, please note that whenever it returns HTML, that you should ensure that you end up with valid HTML. For example, nesting `<html>` tags is illegal. Pass the PHP page through the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) if you're unsure. Otherwise you'd better have to parse the HTML to extract the `<body>` pieces of interest or to use an `<iframe>` instead.

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/someservlet"></iframe>
```

Comment: Is there a way to check the status code on the response header with file_get_contents?

Comment: It's available by [`$http_response_header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) array.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to read the response of a servlet in php and then output it from php?

You can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to the url (Probaly not the best way, but for simplicities sake it the easiest) and then just echo the output.

For example:

```
$content = file_get_content('http://www.google.com');
echo $content;
```

But if you want to be able to login or use the session at the servlet side you will need think of something else. As each request to the server from php will be a new one, it does not store cookies etc.. like browsers do.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation which might do well to be rethought, but, if there are no other options...

If there is a way to actually update the portlet, then I would recommend creating some form of service call -- SOAP, custom RPC, etc -- on the Java side. Technically this is the most correct way to do things.

Failing that, if this is a simple GET request, then use file_get_contents.

If it has to be a POST/PUT/DELETE, then you can use [cURL](http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl). cURL also has the benefit of being able to handle simulated sessions, which means that you are then able to simulate a log in and actions following that (though not without some difficulty).

If you don't have cURL and you need to POST/PUT/DELETE, then the [streams](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) library might be able to give you what you need.

If you don't have the streams library or cURL and you need to POST/PUT/DELETE, then there are [other means](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/) of accomplishing that, but maybe you should really re-rethink that situation.

If all of the above don't work, then you will need to tame the [Spectral Wolf](http://xkcd.com/461/). The Spectral Wolf fears only fire. I can no longer help you, but if you master the Spectral Wolf, he will guide you. Godspeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to do that, you can create a Java app that takes parameters to populate request and response objects, instantiates a servlet, runs the correct method, gets the result and displays it, then call this Java app from PHP.

Or you can use the *experimental* and unrecommended [PHP / Java Integration](http://php.net/java) module.